# Two questions about rate of discount

Tags: actuarial-science

I'm reading through Marcel B. Finan's [*A Basic Course in the Theory of Interest and Derivatives Markets: A Preparation for the Actuarial Exam FM/2*](http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/actuarieshall/mainf.pdf) on my own and I want to make sure I understand discounting. To check that I understand it correctly, I'm copying two of his questions (from page 63, section 8), and my answers, and asking y'all to correct my work.

> The amount of interest earned on *A* for one year is \$336, while the equivalent amount of discount is \$300. Find *A*.

Given are

- $(A-300)(1+i)=A$ and
- $A(1+i)=A+336$

so we get $300(1+i)=336$ so that $i=.12$. Then $.12A=336$ so $A=2800$.

> Calculate the accumulated value at the end of 3 years of 15,000 payable now assuming an interest rate equivalent to an annual discount rate of 8%.

It's just $15000(100/92)^3$, or $19263.17\ldots$.

Comment: They are both correct.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by @mathguy that both are correct.